Are ergodic continuous time processes (strictly) stationary in the limit?
If $X_t$ is a continuous time Markov process in a general state space $X$, say $X=\mathbb{R}^d$. Is it necessarily true that $X_t$ is stationary in the limit, as I believe that any ergodic process converges to their invariant probability measure. And would this notion of stationarity be strict, i.e. the probability law of the process is fixed over time asymptotically? Indeed, if an ergodic process is initialised at some point $x\in X$, then $X_t$ is still ergodic yet not stationary unless $x$ is distributed according to the invariant measure. Similarely, a stationary process might not be ergodic (although I believe if we assume that $X_t$ is recurrent and aperiodic, then this must imply that $X_t$ is ergodic).
If the answer is no, then there must exist examples of processes which are ergodic, but will never be stationary, yet I am uable to find any references, papers or examples online.
Any help is welcome!
